# Проблемы с плавающей точкой

Tags: c++, c

```
double sum;
sum = 179 + 21.48;
```

Должно быть 200.48, но отладчик почему-то говорит `200.47999999999999`

VS2015, Win 10 x64, core i3 broadwell.

Объясните что происходит

Comment: происходит ровно то, что и должно происходить. Читаем детально https://habrahabr.ru/post/112953/

Comment: Ещё более детально [здесь](http://ru.exploringcomputerarithmetic.org/articles/fp/IEEE-754/basics/).